# pexpect AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'

Tags: python, linux, pexcept

What is wrong here?

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
```

I have installed `pip install pexcept`

now when i load it

```
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Jul 13 2018, 13:06:57)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-28)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pexpect
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pexpect.py", line 10, in <module>
    child = pexpect.spawn('ssh %s@%s' % (switch_un, switch_ip))
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'spawn'
>>>
```

## EDIT

Running Linux CentOS 7.x version (64bit)

Answer (score 2):

As stated [HERE](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect/issues/321) `pexpect` is mainly used for UNIX based operation systems. This error comes up when using windows.

Comment: I am running Linux `CentOS 7.x` even i tag `Linux` in question but anyway i have edited my question to clear that out.

Answer (score 0):

install ptyprocess library in your Linux you will not get error

Comment: Subhanshu, to increase the quality of your answer, you might want to give the procedure to install the library and/or details or a link that support your claim why this should solve the issue.

Comment: Subhanshu, please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).